# Totally Antisymmetric Function

Tags: functions

My current implementation for a totally antisymmetric function is like this:

```
g[a__] := Signature[{a}] (g @@ Sort@{a}) /; !OrderedQ[{a}];
g[a__] := 0 /; ! Unequal[a];
```

So I take the list of arguments of f and calculate the signature of the permutation, and put that factor out the front. I then sort to pick a canonical ordering which I put into f.

so I want that eg. f[1,3,2] = -f[1,2,3] and f[1,2,3] = f[2,3,1], and my code above achieves this.
The second line sets any f with two arguments the same to be zero.

Then you could use this f for a wedge product or a minor of a matrix for example.

My code works, but is very slow when doing many rearrangments, as it needs to keep sorting and unioning the list of arguments.

Does anyone have an idea for a faster implementation?

Comment: You might want to add the exact mathematical definition of what you want to achieve. Otherwise, people will have to do their own research or reverse-engineer your code before they can help you.

Comment: Ok thanks Felix is that better now?

Comment: Can you provide an example where your code is slow?

Comment: Just a few things that won't dramatically speed up your code though (I think): `f[Sequence @@ Sort @ List @ a]` can be simplified to `(f @@ Sort @ List @ a)` and I'd generally write `List@a` as `{a}`. Also the `Union` can be avoided with `Unequal[a]` (`Unequal` doesn't only check for equality between consecutive pairs, but between *all* pairs, so it ensures all values are different.) For `Sort @ {a} =!= {a}` you can use `OrderedQ`, or `! Less[a]`.

Comment: Great thanks Martin,  the edited code in my original post is now twice as fast. I assume however that running 'orderedq' and 'sort' is sorting the list twice, so if I could somehow run Sort[a] in the /; and check if it's equal to a, and then keep the sorted list to put into f that would be quicker?
Simon, it's just when I need to run a very large number of evaluations. eg. I set up a wedge product of many differential forms, and then mathematica has to sort the list of differential forms each time it evaluates. So a different implementation which avoids the sorting could be faster maybe.

Comment: @Joe I don't think `OrderedQ` sorts the list (at least I really hope it doesn't). I'm pretty sure its implementation would be similar to my `! Less[a]` suggestion which should run in linear time. You *are* probably sorting twice to determine `Signature` though. I'm not sure there's a way to avoid that, short of writing your own `Signature` that returns the sorted permutation along the way. (Probably based on `Ordering`.) (Also, if you put an @ in front of my name, I'll actually get a notification for your comments.)

Comment: If your function will be used for numeric arguments, or an "easily enumerable" set of symbolic expressions, than maybe you could take advantage of packed arrays and compilation. What is "typical" number of arguments that you're passing to your function? `Unequal` stays unevaluated for "most" of symbolic expressions whether they contain duplicates or not e.g. `Unequal[a, b, b]`,
`Unequal[a, b, c]`, so your current `g` function will remain unevaluated in some cases for which it could give `0` e.g. `g[a, b, b]`.

Comment: I want my function to be able to handle any kind of head. Typical number of arguments can vary, but I'd say currently up to around 20 or 30. As @jkuczm points out, `Unequal` doesn't seem to be able to deal with expressions with more complex heads, eg. `Unequal[d[a] (a + b), d[a] a + d[a] b]` doesn't evaluate explicitly to True,  so I have currently returned to `Union`. @Martin Ender: `Signature+Sort`, is slower than `Ordering+Part`, so something which takes ordering and returns signature which was smaller than the difference would be faster. I'm not sure how to do this? (Thanks for the @ tip)

Comment: I also note that eg. `Signature[{a,a,b}] == 0`, so if it were possible to deal with the two definitions as one definition, somehow altering the `/; !OrderedQ[{a}]`, that could make things faster too? The problem is that `OrderedQ[{a,a,b}] == True` so `Signature` never gets evaluated

Comment: @Joe For 30 arguments *Mathematica*, on my machine, needs about $10^{-5}$ seconds to give result. How many times do you typically need to call this function to make your use case "slow"? Maybe more speed could be gained if, in your use case, there's some exploitable relation between different calls to this function?

Comment: `$hAutoSimplify = True; expr_h /; $hAutoSimplify := Block[{$hAutoSimplify = False}, Signature@expr Sort@expr]` is about two times faster in "generic" case, in my tests. You could add code that will speedup this function in some special cases like already sorted input, or duplicated arguments, but for 30 arguments, overhead will be likely larger than benefits.

Comment: Could you implement this as a Slater determinant? That should be much quicker since it doesn't involve any sorting.