# Automatic simplification of antisymmetric tensor contractions

Tags: replacement

I'm currently using a function `LC[m,n,r,s]` to denote the Levi-Civita symbol $\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ with abstract tensor indices (together with the rules in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173303/define-replacement-rules-for-totally-antisymmetric-objects/178354#178354)). I also have objects such as `V[label,-a]` for e.g. $V_{i,\mu}$ or `Pol[i,-a]` etc which denote vectors.

Is there a slick way I can ensure that `LC` contracted with any two objects that are the same is zero?

e.g. `LC[a,b,c,d]V[i,-a]V[i,-c] = 0`

Ideally, this would happen when using e.g. `Simplify[]` but could just be a seperate function...

Comment: Can you include definitions for  `LC` `V` and `Pol` please?

Comment: They don't have definitions as functions, they are supposed to remain abstract. I mostly just change their formatting using e.g. Format[LC]:=..., then apply rules as necessary.

Incidentally, I want to be able to contract LC with any object, regardless of its definition, and it be zero by the anti-symmetric property of the Levi-Civita symbol.

Comment: What does it mean for two objects to be the same? eg `V[i,-a]` and `V[i,-c]`

Comment: a and c are indices (and i just a label), so this would be $V^{(i)}_a V^{(i)}_c$ in component form. In general, $\varepsilon^{abcd}V^{(i)}_a V^{(i)}_c = 0$, whereas $\varepsilon^{abcd}V^{(i)}_a V^{(j)}_c \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use this rule:

```
LC[___,a_,___,b_,___]*(h_)[x___,-a_,y___]*(h_)[x___,-b_,y___] -> 0
```

To use this together with Simplify, see the [TransformationFuntions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunctions.html) option.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this using a few rules, e.g. with vectors

`LCKill[f_]:= f/.LC[ind1_,ind2_,ind3_]V[iinda_,sinda_]V[iindb_,sindb_]V[iindc_,sindc_]/;!DuplicateFreeQ[{ind1^2,ind2^2,ind3^2,sinda^2,sindb^2,sindc^2}]:>If[!DuplicateFreeQ[{iinda,iindb,iindc}],0,1]*LC[ind1,ind2,ind3]V[iinda,sinda]V[iindb,sindb]V[iindc,sindc]`